# Combining QueryDSL and JaxWS code generation in Maven Build

Tags: java, maven, querydsl

**Edit**: I've now split the project into its component parts, and it turns out that both QueryDSL and JaxWS are innocent. The problem lives elsewhere in the project. The error messages from QueryDSL are a cosmetic problem, but don't break the build.

---

My project uses code generation from both QueryDSL (JPA queries) and JaxWS (web service client code generation from WSDL).

When running a Maven build, the QueryDSL code generation phase produces a large number of errors, as it attempts to process service classes that reference the generated web service client. For example:

```
[INFO] --- jaxws-maven-plugin:1.12:wsimport (default) @ Project---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-apt-plugin:1.0:process (default) @ Project---
/home/adrian/test/Project/src/main/java/uk/co/humboldt/Project/Service/Inspect/Inspect.java:25: package org.supplier.webservice.contractservice does not exist
import org.supplier.webservice.contractservice.ArrayOfString;
```

I've tried to exclude the Service classes from QueryDSL processing:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>process</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
             <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
             <options>
               <querydsl.excludedPackages>uk.co.humboldt.Project.Service</querydsl.excludedPackages>
             </options>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
```

My build eventually fails with

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Project---
[INFO] Compiling 590 source files to /home/adrian/test/Project/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
55 errors
```

I've tried adding the source files using `build-helper` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112622/184998), but it hasn't changed anything. Any suggestions?  I suspect splitting my domain objects and Query classes to a separate JAR will solve the problem, but I'd be happier to fix it in a single POM.

Comment: Does the APT code generation fail or do you just get warnings? The querydsl.excludePackages doesn't restrict the source files to be parsed, just the packages to be skipped for Q-type serialization.

Comment: The APT code generation looks like it has succeeded, so the errors there may be only a cosmetic problem. I think I'll have to split the project into smaller components to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I think it's a cosmetic problem, I am not sure if you can avoid the errors, you will also get errors for references to Q-types at first APT iterations

Comment: It is a purely cosmetic problem.  I've split the project into three modules: one with JPA entities and QueryDSL, one with JaxWS clients, and one with the main application code. It's the application project that fails to build.

Comment: Yes, the compilation error from maven-compiler-plugin is not caused by the Querydsl APT execution.